# Object has no attribute error when attribute is clearly defined and recognized

Tags: python, oop

I am currently trying to use a raspberry pi 4 to control and led strip via an http interface. To do this I have a class called "Strip" which controls what the strip displays. I want to have it so that when a user clicks a button on the http interface a method of the strip is called to light up the strip. However, I am running into the following error:

```
  Error @ line 44: self.strip1.fill_red()
AttributeError: 'MyServer' object has no attribute 'strip1'
```

here is the server class:

```py
from typing import Tuple
from View.strip import Strip
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, strip1: Strip, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.strip1 = strip1

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def _redirect(self, path):
        self.send_response(303)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.send_header('Location', path)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        html = '''
           <html>
           <body 
            style="width:960px; margin: 20px auto;">
           <h1>Welcome to Rahul's Raspberry Pi LED Strip Controller</h1>
           <form action="/" method="POST">
               Strip Options:
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="On">
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Off">
           </form>
           </body>
           </html>
        '''
        self.do_HEAD()
        self.wfile.write(html.encode("utf-8"))

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode("utf-8")
        post_data = post_data.split("=")[1]

        if post_data == 'On':
            self.strip1.fill_red()
            print('On')
        else:
            print('Off')
            self.strip1.clear_strip()
        print("LED is {}".format(post_data))
        self._redirect('/')  # Redirect back to the root url
```

The strip class:

```
import time
import board
import neopixel

#Initialise a strips variable, provide the GPIO Data Pin
#utilised and the amount of LED Nodes on strip and brightness (0 to 1 value)

class Strip:
    BRIGHTNESS = 0.05 #scale of 0-1
    def __init__(self,boardpin:board,num_leds:int,brightness=BRIGHTNESS) -> None:
        self.num_leds = num_leds
        self.pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(boardpin, num_leds, brightness=0.05)
    def fill_red(self):
        """ Fills red"""
        self.pixels.fill((0,220,0))
    def clear_strip(self):
        self.pixels.fill((0,0,0))
```

and the main file:

```
from View.server import MyServer
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer #allows server
from View.strip import Strip
import neopixel
import board


strip1 = Strip(board.D18,55,0.05)  
server_address = ('IPaddresshere', 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, lambda *args, **kwargs: MyServer(strip1, *args, **kwargs))
print('Server running at http://IPaddresshere/')
httpd.serve_forever()
```

When I try to run the above code, The http website is started and I am able to access it, however once I click the "on" button the earlier mentioned error is raised.

Comment: The constructor of `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` already calls one of the `do_...` methods before returning. Set `self.strip1` before calling the constructor.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Aren't I already doing that in the main file? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: The important part is in the constructor of `MyServer`. You just have to set `self.strip1` before calling the super constructor. Change the order of the lines.